# Allow only one checkbox per unique user in Access Table

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm building a list of phone numbers. Each person can have multiple phone numbers. I want a way to indicate which number is the preferred contact number, however, I'm uncertain as to how to make it so that only one number for each member can be selected as "preferred"

Tables:

Members

PhoneNumbers

I have a table with member names and addresses, and a seperate table with phone numbers where the member name is linked to the primary key of the member table. I put a checkbox into the table with phone numbers that is labeled "preferred" and I want to make it so that only one phone number can be checked per unique member name. Meaning, John Doe can have three phone numbers, but only one can be marked as preferred.

I tried to make an index with member name and Preferred and that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just store the preferred phone number in the member's table also? So you have a list of phone numbers, and on the member itself, you have just one field for preferred phone number that when filled is being stored in a field in table member AND also added to phone numbers?

Comment: That would require entering the number twice. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I assume you have a form to fill in the member data? You enter the phone number once for preferred, and an optional field for additional phone numbers. Upon submit, you simply enter the preferred phone number in both tables.

Answer (score -1):

Clearly, the checkbox in the Phone Numbers table does not provide the logic you are trying to implement!
I suggest that you create another column, in the Member table, that contains the id of the "preferred" phone number.
You can use a combo-box to read data from the phone number table and store the selected id in the member table.
If this is too difficult for you, perhaps you can find someone to assist you.